# using we twice in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, vocabulary

Is this correct:

> When we heard the news about the landslide we headed over quickly.

Or do I need a comma after "the landslide"? If so why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn to use capital letters. Sentences must start with a capital letter.

Apart from that, your sentence is correct. It could benefit from a comma, which would serve to indicate the natural division into the two clauses. In speech this would be marked by a significant intonation change (falling on "landslide" then high again on "we headed"). Both "when" and "if" clauses are ended by a comma when they are not at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @CJDennis I believe those are just typographical errors.

Comment: Basically, the answer is fine. And I say spelling and typing/ typographical errors are printed in books. I would change they to it/

Comment: @CJ Thanks for spotting those errors.